# Crashing after using operator new[] in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector

I have a class Vector with array and size fields. When each of two arrays v1 and v2 have more than one element there is a problem with allotment of memory for this arrys in operator of copying. How can I fix it ? Here is a code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vector 
{
private:
    unsigned size;
    double *arr;
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(double *arr, unsigned size); 
    Vector(const Vector &copy);
    Vector &operator= (const Vector &vector);
    friend Vector operator+ (const Vector &varLeft, const Vector &varRight);
    friend ostream & operator<< (ostream &output, const Vector &var);
    friend istream & operator>> (istream &input, Vector &var);
};

int unitTest();

int main()
{
    unitTest();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int unitTest()
{
    Vector v1;
    cin >> v1;
    Vector v2;
    cin >> v2;
    Vector v3;

    cout << "Your Vector v1:" << endl;
    cout << v1 << endl;
    cout << "Your Vector v2:" << endl;
    cout << v2 << endl;

    cout << "Arrays +:" << endl;
    v3 = v1 + v2;
    cout << v3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
    Vector::Vector()
    {
        arr = new double[size];
    };

Vector::Vector(double *arr, unsigned size) : size(size)
{
    arr = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        this->arr[i] = arr[i];
    }
};
```

When operator+ returns value my program crashes after line 'arr = new double[size];' in operator of copying.

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector &copy)
{
    size = copy.size;
    arr = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = copy.arr[i];
    }
}
Vector operator+ (const Vector &varLeft, const Vector &varRight)
{
    Vector res;
    res.size = varLeft.size;

    if (varLeft.size == varRight.size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < res.size; ++i)
        {
            res.arr[i] = varLeft.arr[i] + varRight.arr[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error. Vectors have different size." << endl;
    }
    return res;
}
ostream & operator<< (ostream &output, const Vector &var)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < var.size; ++i)
    {
        output << ' ';
        output << var.arr[i];
    }
    output << endl;
    return output;
}

istream & operator>> (istream &input, Vector &var)
{
    cout << "Enter size of array --> ";
    input >> var.size;
    var.arr = new double[var.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < var.size; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << " element --> ";
        input >> var.arr[i];
    }
    return input;
}
Vector & Vector::operator= (const Vector &vector)
{
   if (this != &vector)
   {
        if (arr != 0)
        {
            delete[]arr;
        }
        size = vector.size;
        arr = new double[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = vector.arr[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Did you implement friendly functions for operator << and >> ? Since you're using direct inputs/outputs of the object. Also the code itself has many errors that would otherwise lead to implicit errors.

Comment: Yes. I implemented it, but forgot to add to my question, wait one minute, please, i'll add it

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please! For example, you're calling `Vector::operator=` but we cannot see how it's implemented.

Comment: Would be great to pass them. Also, you don't have destructor of the Vector class where you shall delete *arr. You didn't either initialize the size of the array, "size"..

Comment: Your whole class can and should be replaced with `std::vector<double>`, which does not crash or leak memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize `Vector::size` in your default constructor, so your program's behavior is undefined.  You need to initialize your `Vector`'s size before allocating your array.

Also, for your `operator+` you will need to either add a `Vector` constructor that takes a size or re-allocate your array after changing the `res`'s size.